# unable to delete data using gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, file, gridview, document

I am building a document uploader web system using asp.net 4.0 .
I am stuck in gridview. I can delete the data from gridview. The data gets deleted in the sql table, but the **document, which is stored in my folder** remains.

I want the document to get deleted when user clicks delete in gridview..is it possible..have been working days on this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `RowDeleted` event of gridview which is fired after the deletion of a row, you have to write logic in this event. like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("DocumentPath"))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete("DocumentPath");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the following line at the end of your GridView's OnRowDeleting event:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("PathToYourDoc")) { System.IO.File.Delete("PathToYourDoc"); }
```

About how to find a document path, you can visit the following link to see different examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/path

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.GetFileName(docPath)));
        {
             
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFileName(docPath));
        }
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            
           
        }



    }

Comment: the code above is what im trying,..and the same problem persist,..i am sorry if i made anything wrong, i am still very new to asp.net .. @Muhammad @ncakmak